# Retrieving all morphedByMany relations in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, polymorphism

In the Laravel documentation, there is the following example for retrieving `morphedByMany` relations, which are many-to-many polymorphic relations.

[Laravel Many to Many polymorphic relations documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations)

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tag extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the posts that are assigned this tag.
    */
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Post', 'taggable');
    }

    /**
     * Get all of the videos that are assigned this tag.
     */
    public function videos()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Video', 'taggable');
    }
}
```

How would I get a list of all `morphed` relations in one query / collection, for instance, `posts` and `videos`, and then if I later added `photos` (or anything), that too?

Comment: Ever find a solution?

Comment: I did but I don't have the code, it was at an old job… what I did was basically use the query builder to get the results and construct the models with the data in a custom collection class.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I use a trick here:

Create a Model `Taggable` for your connection table `taggable` and add a `hasMany` relation to the `Tag` model.

```
public function related()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Taggable::class);
}
```

Within your `Taggable` model create a `morphedTo` relation.

```
public function taggables()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Now you can get all models which are using the tag by calling:

```
$tagged = Tag::with('related.taggables');
```

Comment: I believe this is now the best approach to solving this problem.

Comment: i've made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/ctf0/874e276b8d30e961bb9f359eac956988) for the whole setup + how to get the related items as well

Answer (score 3):

Did you think to use the "union" function of the collections to merge all the different collection in order to retrieve all what you need?

```php
class Tag extends Model
{
    [...]

    /**
     * Get all of.
     */
    public function morphed()
    {
        return $this->video->union($this->posts)->all();
    }
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work for the instance where I added more morphed elements later, although for the specific case of getting videos and posts it would work.

Comment: When you'll add new morphable, you can add a ->union into this function. Of course is not fully automatic but anyways you have to change some lines of code into your model...

Comment: This is not working. For example: I have a Page model, and different models, are connected to this, like Content and Parallax. I have some connected records:
<pre>
page | type | id
1 | content | 1
1 | parallax | 2
1 | content | 3
1 | content | 4
</pre>
* If I do `$this->content->union($this->parallax)->all();` returns three records: 1, 3, 4
* If I do `$this->parallax->union($this->content)->all();` returns three records: 2, 3, 4

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to add a relationship on your Tag class as such

```
public function taggable()
{
    return $this->morphedTo();
}
```

That will use the taggable_id and taggable_type to get the relevant Model that it is tied to.

Comment: That is for polymorphic relations, I'm specifically talking about morphedByMany relationships which is a many-to-many polymorphic relationship. I'll update the question to make that clearer.