# Laravel querying polymorphic relationships with nested many to many items

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 4 tables with the following relationships:

```
class Note extends Model
{
    public function noteable() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class Expense extends Model
{
    public function notes()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Note::class, 'noteable');
    }
}

class Review extends Model
{
    public function notes()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Note::class, 'noteable');
    }

    public function repairs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Repair::class);
    }

}

class Repair extends Model
{
    public function reviews()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Review::class);
    }
}
```

as you can see Note is in the relationship one to many polymorphic and Reviews is in many to many with Repairs.

**I would like to take all Notes that Reviews also has Repairs. How do I do such an operation?**

Following the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-polymorphic-relationships) I am trying to do something like this:

```
    $notes = App\Note::query()
        ->with(['noteable' => function (MorphTo $morphTo) {
            $morphTo->morphWith([
                Review::class => ['repairs']
            ]);
    }])->get();
```

I would like to my query should return something like:

```
[

    {
        "id": 11,
        "noteable_id": 4,
        "noteable_type": "App\\Expense",
        "noteable": {
             "id": 4,
             "name": "Expense",
             "category": "general"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 13,
        "noteable_id": 5,
        "noteable_type": "App\\Review",
        "noteable": {
             "id": 5,
             "name": "Review 5",
             "mileage": 120000,
             "repairs": [..., ...] //what I need
        }
    }

]
```

Comment: What result are you getting?

Comment: It return an array like in my question, but without any repairs key in noteable.

Comment: Can you log the executed queries?

Comment: I also check `App\Review::with('repairs')->get();` which returns me reviews with array of repairs

Comment: What's your Laravel version? What's the result of `dd($morphTo->morphWith([Review::class => ['repairs']]));`?

Comment: php artisan shows laravel framework 6.6.0

Comment: dd show MorphTo instance with noteable_type morphType. What information you would like to see? morphableEagerLoads: [Review => [repairs] ]

Comment: Can you post the whole output to pastebin.com? Is `Review::class` referring to the correct model? I've seen cases where people had multiple models with the same name.

Comment: What's the result of `dd(Review::class)`?

Comment: string "Review"

Comment: works! "App\Review", just namespace mistake. Thank you Jonas for help!

Answer (score 1):

To load your `Repair` models for your `Review`s, try this:

```
if ($type == 'App\Review') {
    $query->with('repairs')
}
```

---

**EDIT :**

I've just done some more reading on `whereHasMorph` and I think i was mistaken as to what it is doing. It is at it's most basic level a `where` clause, designed to constrain the results of the query. What I have suggested above would the the equivalent of joining something to a MySQL subquery. Not what we want!

What you want to do is actually under

> Nested Eager Loading morphTo Relationships

(https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-polymorphic-relationships)

Comment: thanks for the hint, but I still can't handle it. Maybe you know what the problem is now?

Comment: Looking at the changes you have made to your question, i think you are on the right track but I don't think there is much more I can do without setting up an example and tinkering around myself i'm afraid.

Comment: I wonder if there's been any success on this? I'm trying to query a many-to-many polymorphic where any number of users are related to various models Tasks, Businesses, etc via userables table. When I try the Nested Eager Loading morphto Relations I get 'Call to undefined method App\Task::userable()'

Comment: Came across this post with a good solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35948130/retrieving-all-morphedbymany-relations-in-laravel-eloquent