# Use morphTo() in laravel many to many polymorphic

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, polymorphic-relationship

How can I use `morphTo()` in many to many relationships?

Consider I've this four tables:

```
Posts:
 - id
 - title

Videos:
 - id
 - title

Tags:
 - id
 - name

Taggable:
 - id
 - tag_id
 - taggable_type
 - taggable_id
```

In other polymorphic types (like one2one or one2many) we can easily use `$this->morhphTo()` to define a `taggable()` method in our model which returns a list of either `App\Post` or `App\Video`:

```php
class Tag extends Model
{
    public function taggable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
// So when we call taggable(), it returns either App\Post or App\Video
// But what about using this way in many to many polymorphic relations?
```

---

I want something like this in my `App\Tag` model.
Is this possible?

This problem has taken me 8 days so far and I still have no idea.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving all morphedByMany relations in Laravel Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35948130/retrieving-all-morphedbymany-relations-in-laravel-eloquent)

Comment: @Remul I tested it before but it not works well. The `taggables` field in output still null

Comment: Why do you avoid to use [morphToMany / morphedByMany](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations)?